# Get the solution of correct random line coordinates on degree based

Tags: java, swing

Lines made by four Line2D method with **random x2,y2** position. *Every Line "end point" is "origin of" Next Line*. Only first line **y1 position** has fixed and **x1 position** get random value. Now my problem is, some times first line and second line coordinates are almost same or near OR second line and third line OR first line and third line and so on.The following images are showing my problems:
[top one is correct, but bottom right image output is not correct, in this part fourth line almost near to first line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YToNJ.png)[second, third and fourth line almost near each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClFQ1.png)

**For example, from second image, the following values were randomly generated**

> White Line: 1>> x1: 97, y1: 200 and x2: 385, y2: 236

> Red Line: 2>> x1:385, y1: 236 and x2: 90, y2: 187

> Green Line: 3>>>  x1: 90, y1: 187 and x2: 392, y2: 57

> Cyan Line: 4>>> x1: 392, y1: 57 and x2: 196, y2: 135

---

Using the following  type of code:

```
......
randX = RandX();
randY = RandY();
originPT = new Point(randX, 200); 
g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));            
g.setColor ( Color.white);
randX = RandX();
randY = RandY();
endPT = new Point(randX,randY);
g.draw(new Line2D.Double(originPT, endPT));
L1Origin = originPT;
L1End = endPT;
//2nd line
randX = RandX();
randY = RandY();
originPT = new Point(randX,randY);   
g.setColor ( Color.red);
g.draw(new Line2D.Double(endPT, originPT));   
L2Origin = endPT;
L2End = originPT;
//3rd line - Destination
randX = RandX();
randY = RandY();
endPT = new Point(randX, randY);
g.setColor ( Color.green);
g.draw(new Line2D.Double(originPT, endPT)); //GET X2, Y2 POSITION OF LINE 2 FOR X1, Y1
L3Origin = originPT;
L3End = endPT;
System.out.println("Green Line: 3>>>  x1: "+L3Origin.x+", y1: "+L3Origin.y +" and x2: "+L3End.x+", y2: "+L3End.y);
//4th line
randX = RandX();
randY = RandY();
originPT = new Point(randX, randY); 
g.setColor ( Color.cyan);
g.draw(new Line2D.Double(endPT, originPT)); 
L4Origin = endPT;
L4End = originPT;
System.out.println("Cyan Line: 4>>> x1: "+L4Origin.x+", y1: "+L4Origin.y +" and x2: "+L4End.x+", y2: "+L4End.y); ....}//end of method
public int RandX(){
 return MinX() + (int) ( Math.random() * ((MaxX() - MinX()) + 1) ); }
public int RandY(){
 return MinY() + (int) ( Math.random() * ((MaxY() - MinY()) + 1) );}
```

My problem is how to maintain gap in between two lines (at least upto 30 degree). can it possible using degree based gap? Please help me. thank you.

Comment: You don't really want random points.  Divide the width into 4 pieces.  Let's call one piece A.  Divide the height into 4 pieces.  Let's call one piece B.  Generate four random points around (A, B), (3A, B), (3A, 3B), and (A, 3B).  Say, +- 50 deviation.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created a GUI.  Here's one of my many test runs.

[image: Random Shape]

I basically did what I said to do in the comment.

- Divide the width by 4.  Call this piece a.
- Divide the height by 4.  Call this piece b.
- Create the 4 points (a,b), (3a,b), (3a,3b), and (a,3b) with a variation of +- 50.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RandomShape implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RandomShape());
    }
    
    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private final Shape shape;
    
    public RandomShape() {
        this.shape = new Shape();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(shape);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Random Shape");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("New Random Shape");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(this));
        panel.add(button);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        shape.setPoints();
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private Shape shape;
        
        public DrawingPanel(Shape shape) {
            this.shape = shape;
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
                    shape.getWidth(), shape.getHeight()));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5f));
            
            Point[] points = shape.getPoints();
            Point point = points[0];
            Point originalPoint = point;
            for (int index = 1; index < points.length; index++) {
                Point nextPoint = points[index];
                g2d.drawLine(point.x, point.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
                point = nextPoint;
            }
            g2d.drawLine(point.x, point.y, originalPoint.x, originalPoint.y);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private RandomShape randomShape;

        public ButtonListener(RandomShape randomShape) {
            this.randomShape = randomShape;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            randomShape.repaint();
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Shape {
        
        private final int width;
        private final int height;
        
        private Point[] points;
        
        private final Random random;
        
        public Shape() {
            this.width = 640;
            this.height = 480;
            this.random = new Random();
            
            setPoints();
        }
        
        public void setPoints() {
            this.points = generatePoints(width, height);
        }
        
        private Point[] generatePoints(int width, int height) {
            Point[] points = new Point[4];
            int a = width / 4;
            int b = height / 4;
            
            int x = a + getVariance(100);
            int y = b + getVariance(100);
            points[0] = new Point(x, y);
            x = 3 * a + getVariance(100);
            y = b + getVariance(100);
            points[1] = new Point(x, y);
            x = 3 * a + getVariance(100);
            y = 3 * b + getVariance(100);
            points[2] = new Point(x, y);
            x = a + getVariance(100);
            y = 3 * b + getVariance(100);
            points[3] = new Point(x, y);
            
            return points;
        }
        
        private int getVariance(int range) {
            return random.nextInt(range) - range / 2;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public Point[] getPoints() {
            return points;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks dear to give a time and efforts of coding for designed random shape, but my requirement is, first line and last line not closed together. Intersection of two line may be OK. Please check first image, where top left image is correct for my research program whereas bottom right image is not correct for my program, sometimes draw lines in good form like top left image but some times draw line like bottom right image. Can you suggest/rectification in my code who solve this problem Thank You.

Comment: Using these random line positions, research task is calculate the total turn, so that i am using 4 or 5 or 6 lines, system may decide using random class draw 4,5 or 6 lines. I have used the following code for right turn: a.x * (b.y - c.y) + b.x * (c.y - a.y) +  c.x * (a.y - b.y) > 0;

Comment: @Rajesh Kushwaha: Sorry, but you were not precise with your drawing instructions.   Something like, I need 4, 5, or 6 line segments.  The first segment can be at any angle.  The first segment must be exactly 120 pixels long.  The next segment must bend at least 30 degrees and no more than 97 degrees to the left.  The second segment must be exactly 125 pixels long.  Something descriptive and precise like that.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. Sir, my program is running well except line positions as per image. Every Line "end point" is "origin of" Next Line. Only first line y1 position has fixed and x1 position get random value. All program depending upon the random values, such as, angle, position inside in box. 30 degree or other degree is not matter, my problem is only, how to reduce line closeness.